# How to create clickable textcontainer

Tags: java, swing

I have 16 `JTextarea`'s placed on my panel (in gridlayout). I didn't use the design tools netbeans for this. The code generates them for me:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JTextArea vak = maakVak(gridLayoutPanel); //make new JTextArea and add them to gridlayout.
            tekstvakken.add(vak); //save Jtextarea to ArrayList. 
        }
```

This is the method for generating a new `JTextArea` and adding them to the GUI.

```
 public JTextArea maakVak(JPanel p) {
    JTextArea vak = new JTextArea(80, 120);    
    vak.setEditable(false);     
    p.add(vak);
    return vak; //return JTextarea to save in the ArrayList
}
```

I have an `ArrayList` that contains objects from a class that I made for the software. The Objects contain multiple Strings. I need to "print" all the strings from one object to one `JTextArea`, and I do that for the first 16 objects in my `ArrayList` (hence I've only 16 `JTextArea`'s).

This works fine, I have 16 `JTextArea`'s on my GUI and they contain the correct Strings.

Now I want to add more functionality to my software, and I need in some way to make these `JTextArea`'s clickable (when this event occurs, a screen should pop-up where I can change/delete the object).

How is this possible (with minor changes)?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [addMouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener&#40;java.awt.event.MouseListener&#41;)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a mouseListener to JTextArea in maakVak

```
public JTextArea maakVak(JPanel p) {
    JTextArea vak = new JTextArea(80, 120);    
    vak.setEditable(false);  
    vak.addMouseListener(textAreaMouseListener());
    p.add(vak);
    return vak; //return JTextarea to save in the ArrayList
}

private MouseListener textAreaMouseListener() {

    return new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JTextArea vak = (JTextArea) e.getComponent();
            //display popup to make changes
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JTextArea is a java.awt.Component, so it has access to the addMouseListener method.

```
textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(MouseEvent e) {

    //implemented methods go here
});
```

This will create an anonymous inner class which implements MouseListener, and I found it to be the simplest way to do this.

Otherwise, you can just have your class implement MouseListener. This accomplishes the same thing as you still have to override the methods, but it affects the whole class rather than an anonymous class that is only used once.

If the Strings that will be placed in the JTextAreas aren't very lengthy, I would suggest using JButtons instead, so you could use the addActionListener method instead of having to also override four other methods that you won't use.